# A regex puzzles me in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a code like following

```
const regexurl=/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?/;
const regexemail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$/;
let content = "adsfl@asldfdsalf.com asfdsafdasklfjkd fdsaklfjkdlasjfldsajflasdf.comasafdsalf 1238djd.com"
console.log(regexurl.test(content))
console.log(regexemail.test(content))
```

I thought both `regexurl` and `regexemail` should return `true`, cause in the string `content`, it has `email` and `url`,but in fact, `regexurl` returns `true`, but `regexemail` returns `false`. Here are my questions

First, Why does `regexemail` return `false`? There's `email`in `content`.

Second, I want to determine if a string has the url, what should I do? Still using the above example

```
const regexurl=/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?/;
let content = "adsfl@asldfdsalf.com"
console.log(regexurl.test(content))
```

It also returns `true`, but it should return `false`.

Comment: It's okay, as per your email regex it should end with (\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ .

Comment: Also, your content has spaces but your regex does not allows it

Comment: @Rajesh thank you, i fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay, as per your email regex it should end with (.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ .

In below case it's ending with as defined in the regex (either any English alphabet, Number, - or _):

```
let content = "adsfl@asldfdsalf.com"
```

But in case of below, you have space, : and other char's which is not allowed as per email regex.

```
let content = "adsfl@asldfdsalf.com asfdsafdasklfjkd fdsaklfjkdlasjfldsajflasdf.comasafdsalf 1238djd.com"
```

so please split it from that big text and then try the regex.which will be the right approach.

We never check validation like you are trying to do. We always extract that particular content and apply the regex on it.

Comment: Thank you, but in second question, `let content = "adsfl@asldfdsalf.com"`, I use the `regexurl `, but it returns `true`, I think it should return `false`, cause it's an email type, not url type.

Comment: Maybe I should say more clearly, how to determine if a string contains a URL, but does not contain email.

Comment: @matt Your email is satisfying all the condition specified in the URL regex. Try to test this: l@asldfdsalf.com. it will get fail because as per your URL regex there must be at list 2 alphabet char in the starting.

Comment: @matt what you can do you can get the actual site url and validate it then you need to provide these many special char for example @ and all. if you have url like http://www.example.com?hd=dhhd then grab http://www.example.com and validate it. it will save processing time, reduce the complexcity and more readable.